# a:hover not working in css

Tags: html, css

I am implementing style for hyperlink (a and a:hover) but the browser consider the first "a style) only and completely ignore the "a:hover) style, and it works fine when I remove the "a style". I don't know why it has conflict, as I am doing the same thing explained on websites and books.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<nav class="vertical">
    <h4>Course Outline</h4>
    <ol>
        <li><a href="#">The Course of War</a>
            <ol>
                <li><a href="#">1861-1862</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1863</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1864-1865</a></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Aftermath</a>
            <ol>
                <li><a href="#">Lincoln Assassination</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reconstruction</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A New Constitution</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">The United States Is ...</a></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

And here is the CSS

```
 nav.vertical a:hover {
    text-decoration:uderline;
    color: hsla(212%,100%,29%,1);
}

nav.vertical a {
    color: hsla(212%,100%,29%,0.6);
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

I went through all the posts regarding this issue here, but still couldn't fix it.

Comment: You spelled underline wrong.

Comment: @ZackTanner Thanks. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
hsla(212%,100%,29%,1);
```

should be

```
hsla(212,100%,29%,1); /* h = HUE and it's a 0-360 degrees value (not %) */
```

also

```
uderline
```

should be

```
underline
```

```css
nav.vertical a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color: hsla(212,100%,29%,1);
}

nav.vertical a {
    color: hsla(212,100%,29%,0.6);
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<nav class="vertical">
    <h4>Course Outline</h4>
    <ol>
        <li><a href="#">The Course of War</a>
            <ol>
                <li><a href="#">1861-1862</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1863</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1864-1865</a></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Aftermath</a>
            <ol>
                <li><a href="#">Lincoln Assassination</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reconstruction</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">A New Constitution</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">The United States Is ...</a></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</nav>
```

Comment: Bah, just a few seconds faster than me. The `hsla` threw me off since I haven't used that in ages. We still have to support older clients with my current workplace.

Comment: @Trasiva yes, seems like `hsla()` is not supported in IE8... I'm not quite sure about that though.

Comment: I just tested it, can confirm it still doesn't work with IE8 yet.